# How to get iframe parent location

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

Since browsers forbid iframe elements knowing anything about their parents -- http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy -- how does a site like Vimeo get the domain location of the element? -- http://vimeo.com/stats/demo/embeds/range:week

My thoughts were `HTTP_REFERRER` or `document.referrer`.

How is this done?

Comment: you could try postMessage API in Javascript. There an article about it (unfortunately in Polish) http://blog.piotrnalepa.pl/2013/06/24/html5-jak-komunikowac-sie-miedzy-stronami-za-pomoca-html5-postmessage-api/

Comment: @sunpietro Is right, [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) is the way to go for cross frame communication.